# set cell value when cell is editable in jqgrid form edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

hi i am using JQGrid and want to set value of a cell to zero when i edit the row and whatever the value of the cell is like if cell value is 103.50 i want to to set to 0
i try

```
editoptions:{dataInit : function (elem){$(elem).val("0");}}
```

and it works for only new but i want to reset value of cell to "0" even when i use form edit.

i also try

```
editoptions:{defaultValue:"0"}
```

and

```
editoptions:{value:"0"}
```

but all is working when use form edit for new row and when try to edit it show first time the default "0" value but when i cancel and again edit form then cell value is set in the text input field

i know its not logical but want to do for customer requirement and also search a lot for it
but unable to find any related proper answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
beforeShowForm: function($form) {
setTimeout(function() {
    $form.find('input#credit.FormElement').val(0);
    },50);
}
```

works for me as when load the form i reset the value of Credit;

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the value of the cell, when selecting the row, if it an inline edit.

```
onSelectRow: function (id) {
                if (id) {
                    selectedRowId = id; // save current row ID 
                    var myCellData = grid.jqGrid('getCell', selectedRowId , 'MyColName');
                }
            },
```

where id the row id, then you can find the cell value

Hope this helps you. Enjoy jqGrid.

Comment: no i am not using inline edit i want to do that in form edit when 
editing the row.